# Discord.js bot dosnt have permission to manage Nicknames

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I gave my discord bot the admin permission, and put the role above every other role, but it seems like the bot dosnt have the permission to change NickNames even if i check for it.

```js
if (msg.content === '!ping') {
    msg.reply('Pong!')
    msg.reply(msg.author.username)
    msg.member.setNickname('RandomName').catch(e=>console.log(e))
    console.log(msg.guild.members.find("id",client.user.id).hasPermission("MANAGE_NICKNAMES"));
}
```

It gives me the answer `true` to the check if I have the permission, but it gives me the error: `DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions` to the setNickname Command.

Comment: Assuming that you are testing this command yourself, in a guild that you crated, the bot will not be able to change your nickname. Guild owner has the highest hierarchy and the bot (or no one for that matter) will be able to change the owner's nickname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bot can't change the nickname of a guild owner or a member with a higher role. Check to make sure that the user isn't the owner first.

```js
try {
  if (msg.guild.me.permissions.missing('MANAGE_NICKNAMES')) return msg.reply('I\'m missing permissions.');
  if (msg.author.id === msg.guild.ownerID) return msg.reply('I can\'t change your nickname.');

  msg.member.setNickname('test');
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```